# How to pass a list from one function to another in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have created a function that returns a list a list of scores. now I want that list to be used in another function

here is my app.py file

```
@app.route('/getmarks', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getmarks():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        marks = list(map(float,(request.form['score']).split()))
        return render_template('results.html', marks=marks)    
    return render_template('getmarks.html')

@app.route('/displaygraph/marks', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def displaygraph(marks):

    return render_template('graphs.html', marks=marks)
```

How do I get that marks list in my `displaygraph` function?

Comment: Where's the function that returns a list of scores? `getmarks` will return a rendered webpage

Comment: Okay cool, I am new to this, so how can I get the list of scores(marks) in my other function? do I need to write a return statement and return just the list(marks)?

Comment: just make that variable global.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't make that variable global. Extract a function that parses the request and reuse in both handlers.

Comment: Thank You all, I solved this